# persistent custom-steps in Gremlin using Neo4J Graph-DB

Tags: groovy, neo4j, gremlin

i am using "gremlin-groovy 2.1.0" connectig to a Neo4J-DB via the gremlin console:

```
gremlin> g = new Neo4jGraph('/home/user/neo4j-enterprise-1.7.2/data/graph.db')
```

so far no problems. Now i want to create some custome steps via

```
gremlin> Gremlin.defineStep('example', ...)
```

the custom step works fine, but after disconnecting from the neo4j-DB and exit:

```
gremlin> g.shutdown()
gremlin> exit
```

and reconnecting to the DB, the custom 'example' isn't available.

So my question is, how to store a custom-step defined via Gremlin.defineStep persistent? AND ist it possible, to save the defineStep()-Code in a file, maybe in the gremlin-lib directory, to use this custom step everytime i need it?

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using defineStep() doesn't persist your step in the graph itself.  It's merely using the dynamic programming facilities of groovy to extend the language with your step.  Your custom step is therefore only available within the Gremlin instance that you run your defineStep in.    In that sense there is no way to "persist" a step globally.

However, you can simply save your script containing your steps and other useful functions in a .groovy file and load it at the gremlin prompt with the console load function like:

`\. path/to/my-custom-steps-and-functions.groovy`

There are open issues in Gremlin to automate this process for both Gremlin and Rexster, so you can expect that in a future TinkerPop release, it will be possible to trigger the load of a script like this at startup so that it's ready to go right at the outset of your session.

Comment: so `gremlin> . ./mystep.groovy` should work? it does not. Is the dot on the beginning required?

Comment: sorry...stackoverflow formatting messed up my answer.  i just edited it.  note that if you enter a "?" on the gremlin console you will get help for groovy console commands.